# Making copy of /bin/ping exectuable

Tags: command-line, permissions, ping, setcap

I have copied my /usr/bin/ping file to another location (my home directory) with just a typical `cp /bin/ping p` command and then it stopped working, because the lack of permissions. Precisely:

> Ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted.

I know that `sudo` would rather solve my problem, but I **should not log in as a superuser**.
I also know that it is (probably) all about the lack of some permissions or capabilities (in fact `getcap` for my copied file shows it's missing the original ping's capabilities), but unfortunately I am not able to use `setcap` without root privileges .. or maybe I am? Somehow?

How could I solve this problem and be able to use my ping file copy `./p`?

Comment: My `ping` executable is not located at `/usr/bin/ping` but at `/bin/ping`. Can you please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -l ./p /bin/ping /usr/bin/ping`? And can you use `sudo` (i.e. do you have an admin account or just a restricted one)? You will probably need it to fix this, I think.

Comment: Why do you need to work with a copy of `ping` at all by the way?

Comment: @ByteCommander, of course you are right. My problem is actually about Fedora, not Ubuntu. But if I change the path to `bin/ping` as you said it is actually still a good question.

Comment: @ByteCommander, that's some kind of assignment or rather a challenge from my ex-teacher and I'd like to beat it.

Comment: If you are using Fedora, could be selinux as well ;)

Comment: So you must operate on an account without `sudo` privilege and manage to get a copy of the `ping` executable running. I understand.

Comment: @ByteCommander, exactly, sir.

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak Based on the information in this thread, your best bet is to find a security flaw in your operating system, and get a privilege elevation to root. No other easy way to do it as your current user. ICMP is too far down in the stack for the kernel to give you access to that. UDP and TCP are fair game, but going down to layer 3 is tricky as an ordinary user.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay, Yep. I have already realised that it's not possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44168 May  7  2014 /bin/ping
```

The `s` in `rws` means `ping` is setuid. When you run it, it runs *as* its owner, root.

That's how it has the permission to ping. You can `sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep ./ping` but ultimately ICMP is under "raw sockets" so this isn't a small number of operations. It would allow another application to spoof network traffic.

For this to be "secure" and ping, the file would have to be owned by root to stop the application being edited by other users.

Perhaps `setcap` will one day let you specify a hash signature for executable too.

Comment: You should maybe add that one would need to run `chmod 4755 ./p && sudo chown root: ./p` to set the correct original permissions for the file.

Comment: It's probably better to grab a fresh copy in a way that preserves file attributes `sudo cp -a /bin/ping ./p` (just in case something untoward has already happened to the file).

Answer (score 4):

As [noticed by Oli](https://askubuntu.com/a/699677/16395), `ping` is setuid ---  run as root when called.

**However**, if you copy it with

```
cp -a /usr/bin/ping ./myping
```

the target will lose the setuid bit --- you copy the file, but you can only create files with your own user's permissions, and your regular user can't create a setuid-root binary. It will be a huge security hole otherwise (now you can modify your copy of `ping`)!

If you want to maintain the setuid bit, you must copy with `sudo cp -a`. No way around this, I hope.